# Using input variable in two controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a problem using one "input variable" but in to different controllers (and models), I'm using code igniter.

I have a form in `view1`, once submit we call `controller1`, the `controller1` verifies if `$this->input->post(name)` exists or not:

```
if exist {echo exist }
else {
// redirect to another controller2 when you should click "add" to add
// "$this->input->post(name)" to a table
}
```

now I don't know how to use the same variable `$this->input->post(name)` in the second `model2`.

I'd be thankful if you help me.

Comment: While redirecting send value through URL and get it in controller2

Comment: or you can save in session and can use anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in controller 1:

```
redirect('/Controller2/function2/value');
```

In your controller 2 something like this:

```
public function function2($value){
    // send value to the model
}
```

Also you can do it with sessions but the choice is yours

Answer (score 0):

you can save it into a variable and pass it

for example

```
    //get the variable and save it
    $myVariable = $this->input->post('name');
    //load the model
    $this->load->model('model2');
    //now send the variable to the model 
    $this->model2->doSomethingElse($myVariable);
```